# SSMS 2008 Connecting to SQL Server 2012 - Intellisense?

Tags: intellisense, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008

Has anyone had any luck getting intellisense in SSMS 2008 to work when connecting to a SQL Server 2012 (SP1) instance?

For me, it appears that this is not working.

Whilst I would consider upgrading to SSMS 2008 R2 (if intellisense works there against a 2012 instance), unfortunately I can't upgrade to SSMS 2012 at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using SSMS 2008R2, and when I connect to my 2012 instance, I have intellisense working (as SSMS 2008R2 replaces SSMS 2008, I can't test the other way!)

In options -> Text editor -> All languages -> "Auto list members" is ticked.

Screenshot showing intellisense working (you can see in the object explorer this is a 2012 instance) :

[image: intellisense on 2012]

Help -> About on SSMS:

[image: SSMS 2008]

Perhaps this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173434.aspx) might help you solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks Bridge - this gives me some hope that I won't need to go all the way to SSMS 2012 - I've checked my settings a few times (as well as 'refresh local cache'), but to no avail.  Interestingly the 2008 / 2008 R2 versions of the MSDN page you supplied state intellisense works only vs. MSSQL 2008 (although evidently this is not the case for SSMS 2008 R2!).

Comment: @WillA There's still hope! I wouldn't 100% rely on any MS documentation to be honest - experiment. All the shared tools of 2008 are upgraded (not just SSMS) but I've not encountered any issues using SSMS 2008R2 tools with a vanilla 2008 instance. If you've got a test machine, could try on that if you don't want to take the plunge.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - with some further research I'm feeling happier with the idea of moving to 2008 R2 even though our SSIS / SSAS server is stuck on 2008 at the mo' - so looks like that's the way to go.